# React component rendered from object does not get unmounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code, where I need to run clean-up when unmounting each component step. I've set a useEffect on each Step to check if the component has been unmounted. When the parent gets a new currentStep it swaps the currently active component but the clean-up never runs. I'm wondering if this has to do with the nature of the component being rendered from an object

```
const Step1 = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("doing things here");
    
    return () => {
      console.log("clean-up should happen here but this won't print")
    }
  }, []}
}

const StepMap = {
  step1: <Step1/>
  step2: <Step2/>
  step3: <Step3/>
}


const Parent = ({ currentStep }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      { StepMap[currentStep] }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Alternatively this piece of code does run the clean-up, but I do find the former cleaner

```
const Parent = ({ currentStep }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      { currentStep === "step1" && StepMap[currentStep]}
      { currentStep === "step2" && StepMap[currentStep]}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Why does the first approach not work? is there a way to make it work like the second while keeping a cleaner implementation?

Comment: Can you provide the caller? When I do a little demo, it DOES print the cleanup statement.

Comment: here's the little demo - it prints the statement when i click the buttons https://codesandbox.io/s/step-demo-fjt836

Comment: Interesting, your example is nearly the same as the one I'm trying, there is likely some different reason as to why clean-up isn't happening in my usecase. Either way, what I thought was the issue doesn't seem to be. I'll re-examine my code and inspect more thoroughly. Thank you!

Comment: If React thinks it's the same component you can override this behavior by adding `key={currentStep}`, then your component will always be re-created when currentStep changes.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to write javascript inside `jsx` we have write it inside `{}` curly braces like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Step1 = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Step1 doing things here");

    return () => {
      console.log("Step1 clean-up should happen here but this won't print");
    };
  }, []);
  return <div>stepOne</div>;
};

const Step2 = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Step2 doing things here");

    return () => {
      console.log("Step2 clean-up should happen here but this won't print");
    };
  }, []);
  return <div>steptw0</div>;
};

const Step3 = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Step3 doing things here");

    return () => {
      console.log("Step3 clean-up should happen here but this won't print");
    };
  }, []);
  return <div>stepthree</div>;
};

export const StepMap = {
  step1: <Step1 />,
  step2: <Step2 />,
  step3: <Step3 />,
};

export const Parent = ({ currentStep }) => {
  return <div>{StepMap[currentStep]}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [steps, setSteps] = React.useState("step1");
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setSteps("step2"), 5000);
    setTimeout(() => setSteps("step3"), 15000);
  }, []);
  return <Parent currentStep={steps} />;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I know, I just missed that when writing the sample code. The issue still stands

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-9887h1 here is `codesandbox` of this example nothing change and it totally works fine

Comment: you are doing something wrong because it perfectly works in my environment as well as in `codesandbox`

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue. Both pieces of code work, but the clean-up isn't triggered in the first snippet. Try adding a useEffect to the steps and you'll see that clean-up is never triggered

Comment: I've updated the code again to reflect the issue more accurately

Comment: got it now you have updated question will update my answer as well

Comment: updated the answer this is what you are trying to achieve ? lemme know otherwise I will delete my answer

Comment: that's correct, looking at the other reply I got it seems I was wrong in assuming that clean-up doesn't happen because I was rendering from an object. I need to do some more digging to figure out what the issue is. I do appreciate your help though